# Parsing Json data from a file and as a string

Tags: c#, html, json, parsing

I have a json file as following:

[image: JSON File]

and I wish to parse them using C#, I tried the Json from *Newtonsoft* but when I parsed it I got a **null** and I also tried to paste the Json data as a string in C# but seems like there are many syntax errors in a json data string.

```
var source = File.ReadAllText("Test/jsonfile.json");
dynamic stuff = JObject.Parse(source);
string name = stuff.hotelID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScriptSerializer with its Deserialize method.

```
var source = File.ReadAllText("Test/jsonfile.json");
var JavaScriptSerializer MySerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var myObj = MySerializer.Deserialize<T>(source);
var htoelId = myObj.searchResults[0].hotelID;
```

where T is your object.

Also, if you have large files, set

```
MySerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer { MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue };
```

Comment: Yes, thank you  but i still dont get how to get the ID or other properties in this case, could you suggest me some more ideas? Thanks @arpad

Comment: @bluewonder I've updated my answer. You can map your object as it is. I see that you have a list of search results. So maybe the answer should be myObj.searchResults[0].hotelID . But that is for you to decide.